# Mysqli::close() vs. $stmt->close()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am a little confused as to how prepared statements of mysqli are handled internally.

`mysqli::prepare($query);` returns a `mysqli_stmt` object. The documentation says that statements should be closed immediately after they are no longer needed. So far, so good.

However, do statements still need to be closed explicitly if I call `mysqli::close()`? Also, do the statement objects have their own database connection and will continue to work reliably even in a situation like this:

```
<?php
$oDb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$oStmt = $oDb->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_test (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)");

$oDb->close();

$oStmt->bind_param('sss', 'Hello', 'World', '!');
$oStmt->execute();
//do some more stuff
$oStmt->close();
```

Or will calling `mysqli::close()` also close all statements?

Comment: Besides that you could just try it and maybe answer the question yourself, it is a good question.

Comment: Note that I asked if it will continue to work "reliably". I've become wary of just testing one case and conclude it will always (or never) work. Especially in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, calling mysqli::close() also close all statements.
If you are calling this function as the last operator in your code, you don't need to call it either.

So, just don't bother.